# AJAX URL JSON. Параметры URL при GET запросе

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, url

Доброго времени суток Стаковцы! Где можно почитать про параметры передаваемые в url, их именование и комбинирование. `"https://some_server.com/puth_db_json/table?id=3"` типа такого. В общем где конкретно описываются операторы к примеру  выборки с id=1 по id=6?

Comment: обычно такие вещи в http запросах, по моей практике, происходят путем конкатенации. У вас есть логика получения `id` и конкретный `id` вы подключаете путем `https://some_server.com/puth_db_json/table` + `id`.

Так же в зависимости от вашего back-end это может быть одним из дополнительных параметров `data` например `data: { id : id }`

Comment: ... я сначала прочитал "Стакановцы")

Comment: где почитать - не знаю. Надо гуглить. Но тема, вроде простая. В моем понимании это выглядит так: все что до `?` это, как бы, путь к файлу (но могут быть нюансы - зависит от бэкэндера); все, что после-  строка запроса в формате `ключ=значение`, ключи между собой разделены знаком `&`.

Comment: таки да всё зависит от бэка - дали доки как настроен сервер на запросы, всё ок. Спасибо за внимание!